# how to make secure sign up form

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i want my sign up form to be secure from hacker..i want all secret information can't easily open by wrong people..

i wan't some data become encrypted..

how to make it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

**[PHP Security Guide](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)**

For form security, have a look at:

**[PHP Security Guide: Form Processing](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html)**

I would suggest you for **[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)** actually:

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in    PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious    code (better known as
>   XSS) with a thoroughly audited,
>   secure yet permissive whitelist

Comment: This will secure the actual sign up process. Additionally you'll want to hash passwords (using a salt), in case someone gains access to your database.

Comment: @Klox: Then you can go for excellent captcha named reCaptcha: http://recaptcha.net/. It is also used by this site.

Comment: @sarfraz: what is the different using reCaptcha with basic captcha?

Comment: @klox: The recaptch is improved and better one.